# Why is the "Source Code Locations" page missing on eclipse 3.6 (Helios)

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, target-platform

I'm trying to add JFace source code on my Target Platform in Eclipse 3.6.

Many [help](http://help.eclipse.org/ganymede/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/guide/tools/preference_pages/source_code_locations.htm) [page](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rsmhelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/guide/tools/preference_pages/source_code_locations.htm) on the internet refers to a "Source Code Locations" tab from the Target Platform preferences page.

I do *not* have that tab on a fresh Eclipse 3.6 including RCP development (eclipse-rcp-helios-SR1-RC4-win32.zip). Here's a screenshot of my Target Platform preferences page :
[image]

Any idea how add source code to my target platform ?

Answer (score 3):

Many help page might refer to that tab, but the [Eclipse Helios page](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp) doesn't.
As far as I can see, this is no longer available with Eclipse 3.6.

You can add your source when [exporting your plugin](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/guide/tools/export_wizards/export_plugins.htm), but that is not exactly the same.

The "[Generating Source Features and Plug-ins](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/tasks/pde_source_generation.htm)" is still there though.
It was the alternative mentioned by the [old Ganymede Help page](http://help.eclipse.org/ganymede/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.pde.doc.user/guide/tools/preference_pages/source_code_locations.htm)

> **Declared Source Locations**
>
> An alternative way to ship source code locations is to use declared (pre-defined) source locations.
> This is done by using the **`org.eclipse.pde.core.source`** extension.
> A plug-in defining this extension will be treated as a source location.
> The extension point schemas and source archive(s) for a plug-in are located in a unique subdirectory under one of these source code locations.
> The name and structure of the subdirectories must follow a specific convention.